# Postman gives error for REST based POST methods

Tags: angularjs, scala, postman, akka-http, spray-client

I am using `POSTMAN` app for doing `REST call (POST, GET)` to my Scala Akka Application. if i do the same call from angularJS it works but when i fire it from POSTMAN it gives following error :

```
There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:
Expected 'application/json'
```

My `POST` Call is :

```
http://localhost:8090/user/signUp
```

which contains 3 request parameters which i added in `Body` tab of Postman.
my Header requires one value i.e `App_Id` which i added in `Headers` also i added

```
Content-Type : application/json
```

in Header. but still postman gives above error.

My Application Code is :

```
val route =
    post {
      path("user" / "signUp"){
        headerValueByName("App_Id") { app_id => {
            handleWith {

                   //application specific implementation

            }
        }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Did you add the parameters are form-data or raw? Based on the error I would guess that the body of the POST is not a valid JSON object. Can you show the actual data management part of the POST in angular since it is a success and will be extremely informative?

Comment: As @tokkov mentioned, you are telling the server one thing but doing another.  You are saying that the body is json when in fact, it appears to be form urlencoded content data.  Try changing the content type to: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and see if that works.

Comment: Hi @tokkov, i tried adding params in form-data still it gives error like         _"The request content was malformed:
Unexpected character '-' at input index 1 (line 1, position 2), expected DIGIT:
------WebKitFormBoundaryd0iYY8aDZPZxCE28?
 ^"_

Comment: @cmbaxter thanks for suggesting but when i changed content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but  it gives same error `There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:
Expected 'application/json'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @tokkov & @cmbaxter for your help..finally it is worked.

I added `Content-Type : application/json and App_Key : xxx` in Headers.
and request parameters in `Raw` with type `Json(application/json)`. Like this:

```
{
    "email" : "xxx",
    "name" : "TEST NAME",
    "password" : "xxx"

 }
```

So My problem is with adding Request Parameters which i would to add in `raw` but i am trying in `form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded`